# Use control from cs file (wpf)

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I'm sorry I'm new to C# and WPF.
I tried to use 3rd party control from *.cs file downloaded from:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/75847/Virtualizing-WrapPanel

the article described to use the control:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{StaticResource boundCollection}">
   <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
       <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingWrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" /> 
       </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel> 
</ListBox>
```

I have copied the cs file to my project's folder and added it by drag and dropping to solution explorer then change the namespace to my project's namespace. But it display the following error:

```
Error   1   The tag 'VirtualizingWrapPanel' does not exist in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'. Line 30 Position 22.   C:\Users\mbp2011\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\@Experiment\ThumbnailsView\ThumbnailsView\MainWindow.xaml    30  22  ThumbnailsView
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Make sure and add an xml namespace that matches the namespace of the usercontrol like the following

xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:MyNamespace;assembly=MyAssembly"

Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747086.aspx

Comment: then you would use <custom:VirtualizingWrapPanel ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add a reference in your Xaml, its kind of the same as adding a ref (using) in your cs files

Example:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication8.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

        // Add a reference to the namespace that contains VirtualizingWrapPanel 
        xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:the namespace of the VirtualizingWrapPanel"

        Title="MainWindow" Height="233" Width="405" Name="UI" WindowStyle="ToolWindow">
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{StaticResource boundCollection}">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>

                // then use the namespace to access the VirtualizingWrapPanel 
                <controls:VirtualizingWrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    </ListBox>
</Window>
```